# Is there a positive version of "the final nail in the coffin"?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Say that you are considering getting chickens.
You've been noticing all the ways you would benefit, a farmer you know told you that he will have chicks for sale soon, and so on, but you don't know when you'll have the time to build a coop for them.
Then your boss tells your team to take an extra week off after Christmas, in reward for outstanding work (okay, this may be rather contrived; it's just an example :) ).

What is an expression for that final confirmation that you should do something or that something is good or right?
Like when lots of things are going wrong, and then there's that final blow, the "final nail in the coffin"; but in this case, things are going right, and then there's a final confirmation of the thing.

Comment: No excuses . . .

Comment: [the stars align](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/stars-align)

Comment: Things like "the icing on the cake don't convey the though I've got. After looking through those links, "the clincher" (comment on ["Last straw on camel's back" but positive? [duplicate]](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/193048/406102) seems to be the best for what I had in mind.

Comment: [This answer to What expression would be the opposite of "Deal Breaker"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/63031/406102) satisfies me.